# Excel VBA to Transpose a range in 1 workbook, then transfer value to 2nd workbook append to end

Tags: excel, vba

I'm still new to VBA and learning - I have a need to copy values (say Range A in workbook A) and transfer the values to Range B in Workbook B. The values need to be transposed, and slightly restructured (1 column to move to first column).

To me, I can see two ways of doing this that fulfill needs. 
1.) Restructure the Range A to vertical set into a new sheet, then transfer values from full range and append to bottom of Workbook B. This creates more data but eliminates the need for finding the header.

2.) Keep Range A/Workbook A format and use Loops/Arrays? to find values, if new value exists on header in workbook A, add value to header row in Workbook B - otherwise, find corresponding value header in workbook A to Workbook B and transfer value. This keeps the data consolidated, which I like - but far more complex than what I know how to do.

My current code is a bit of a mess. Initially, i was trying to do option 1 above, but starting with blind copy/transfer values as a start, then modify to optimize the flow....and it's using copy/paste special transpose which is very slow. I'm having a hard time as I'm still not familiar with Loops, but more specifically - the transpose function. I heard it needs to be set as an array.

I'm not looking for someone to solve the code for me, just need help understanding the the Loop/Transpose Array.

```
Sub test()

Dim Cell As Range
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim lastRow2 As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim LastColumn2 As Long
Dim TargtRng As Range
Dim TargtRng2 As Range
Dim TargtRng3 As Range
Dim TargtRng4 As Range


'Chronology
With Sheets("Consolidated Change List")


For Each Cell In .Range("A4:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    If Cell.Value <= Range("F2").Value Then
     ' Copy initial data set
     lastRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row + 1
     Set TargtRng = .Range(Cell, Cell.Offset(, 8))
     Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(lastRow, "A").Resize(TargtRng.Rows.Count,   TargtRng.Columns.Count).Value = TargtRng.Cells.Value

     ' Copy and Transpose other Rms/Rates
        'Target Range 2 is the Room types to be transposed
         LastColumn = Worksheets("Consolidated Change List").Cells(3, Worksheets("Consolidated Change List").Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
         Set TargtRng2 = Worksheets("Consolidated Change   List").Range(Range("J3"), Range("J3").End(xlToRight))
         TargtRng2.Copy
         Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(lastRow, "H").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True

        ' Target Range 3 is the cell row within loop, new rates to transpose
        'LastColumn2 = .Cells(Cell, Worksheets("Consolidated Change List").Columns.Count).End(xlToRight).Column
        Set TargtRng3 = .Range(Cell.Offset(, 10), Cells(Cell, LastColumn))
        TargtRng3.Copy
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(lastRow, "I").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True

        ' Target Range 4 is the Change order through Segment to be copied over
        Set TargtRng4 = .Range(Cell, Cell.Offset(, 7))
        lastRow2 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(lastRow, "A"), Cells(lastRow2, "G")).Value = TargtRng4.Cells.Value






        End If
    Next Cell
End With


End Sub
```

[Requirements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1DKx.png)
[image: Requirements]

[Screenshot of Current - Workbook A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49AEY.png)
[image: Screenshot of Current - Workbook A]

[Screenshot of Expected Transposed for option 1 above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgKlQ.png)
[image: Screenshot of Expected Transposed for option 1 above]

Requirements:

1. Copy values in range A from workbook A and copy/transpose (prefer transfer values not paste special for speed) into Workbook B, Range B
2. This sample file does not depict 2 workboos; visual reference of what's in workbook A (Current Tab) and expected value in Workbook B(Expected Transposed Tab)
3. There may be blanks with Range A under the header values, These blanks should be ignored/bypassed as not needed
4. Range B in workbook B is slightly restructured in that the Dt_TmStamp column is moved to first column
5. Ideally, smart logic to find the exact match to transfer versus blind copy/transpose. Can keep the structure in Range A and Workbook A to Workboo B if the below bullets included:
6. The vba would need to find the corresponding Header Value within workbook B - this is because Header Values may change (sort order, old values removed, new values added)
7. It would need to restructure slightly and maintain the Dt_TmStamp column to be first column in workbook B
8. The header values would remain in first row in Workbook B/RangeB - however, new values should be added at the end, old values can be retained
9. The table grows in workbook B as values are added; would need to append to last row. Header values remain in first row

Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, trying to upload vba code. One moment

Comment: Don't forget to post "requirements" (instead of image).

Comment: Thank you, I've listed them out. Is it possible to attach the sample excel file?

Comment: As far as i know, NO. But you can use other services and post the link to the file on that server.

Comment: It may be difficult to build logic as your base data has in its header number of accounts though not shown in sample data but becomes clear from consolidated sheet for example `ABC126`. For such unstructured data there has to be identifying unique key which can integrate rows and columns data union / intersection. Arrays , transpose comes later. Your situation may require union/intersection of range segments. VBA will be helpful in structured data. Unstructured data has to rationalized by conventional means.Else structure of your consolidated sheet should be firm with a unique key.

Comment: For the base data - The header contains account items like ABS126 - these are sample data values not the actual values. The actual values in my workbook are unique but I agree the structure is not ideal. Trying to work with what i have.

It could be possible to use a complex formula to look up the values based on column H/I and maintain the Columns A through I - but not certain how that would impact performance...Almost seems like an Array formula with the Nth degree would be needed and that many Arrays would be very slow in processing.

Comment: How would i setup the union/intersection - I could try that part first but not familiar with the syntax